# Gradient with alpha in tableviewcell gets darker with each scroll

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, gradient, uitableview

I am trying to set transparent gradient color in my tableviewcell. Everything works fine in the first load but with each scroll, the color are loaded again and the gradient seems to be darker and darker with each scroll and with each scroll the tableview seems to be laggier. Here's my code for implementing gradient color :-

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.contentView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient(cell.bounds), atIndex: 1)
}

func gradient(frame:CGRect) -> CAGradientLayer {
    let layer = CAGradientLayer()
    layer.frame = frame
    layer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0,0.68)
    layer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0,0.75)
    layer.colors = [UIColor.clearColor().CGColor,UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2).CGColor]
    return layer
}
```

Comment: cell reusable not working ...I think. Again and again it's allocating, it's getting  darker while scrolling the view

Comment: Cells are reusable objects which means you need to insert the layer only once in upon initializing them *(`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` might be a good place to add that layer if you don't want to create a custom cell class)*. Then you can update layer's frame in either `willDisplayCell` or `layoutSubviews` method of the cell in question.

Comment: It's definitely an issue with reusing cells. Have in mind that if you are reusing cells (you should) and you set transparency of the cell =  cell.trasparency + 0.1 (a pseudo code just to show the increment) each time you scroll, the transparency will increment

Comment: I too think the problem here is that cell deque is not working incase of the gradient. How do i stop the gradient from adding further. i tried loading from the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath too but same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Add a subview to your Cell like and connect it to your View controller:

[image]

```
class MyCell : UITableViewCell {     
    @IBOutlet weak var bgView: UIView!        
}
```

**2)** Remove your line from **willDisplayCell** method a move it to your **cellForRowAt**() method, updated like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell

    if(cell.bgView.layer.sublayers == nil) {
        cell.bgView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient(frame: cell.bounds), at: 1)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Sorry, when troubles with soft swift incompatiblity, I was deploying on Swift 3.0.

Comment: @pedrouan your solution is work for me single static color but my issue is when I pass the dynamic color for each cell the gradient is not changed initial when I scroll the table view it will be changed but different from actual pass index. please help me. what I can do?